# Trying to use Twitter API but my code wont run anything

Tags: twitter, streaming, ipython, tweepy

I am trying to use the twitter API in order to stream all tweets that include Michigan State, Spartans, and MSU. After I can figure this out I want to use different big10 key words. However, I run this code and I can't get past
ln (*) no matter how long I wait nothing is happening. Is there any issue with my code? Or how to I get the display of this information so I can analyze it?

THANK YOU!

```
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy import Stream

#Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API 
access_token = "ENTER YOUR ACCESS TOKEN"
access_token_secret = "ENTER YOUR ACCESS TOKEN SECRET"
consumer_key = "ENTER YOUR API KEY"
consumer_secret = "ENTER YOUR API SECRET"


#This is a basic listener that just prints received tweets to stdout.
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        print data
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print status


if __name__ == '__main__':

#This handles Twitter authentification and the connection to Twitter Streaming API
    l = StdOutListener()
    auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
    auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
    stream = Stream(auth, l)

#This line filter Twitter Streams to capture data by the keywords: 'MichiganState', 'Spartans', 'MSU'
    stream.filter(track=['MichiganState', 'Spartans', 'MSU'])'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `on_status(self, status)` in the listener class:

```
class StdOutListener(tweepy.StreamListener):

    def on_status(self, status):
        print status.text
        print status.id
```